# Referencing Edited Row Instead of getLastRow

Tags: google-apps-script

My current code is listed below (triggered by on change). It creates a calendar event when a new "lead" is entered in our lead sheet via AppSheet. It currently only runs when a new lead aka new row is added. I would like it to also run when the appointment date is added or modified, so if a lead is entered but appointment is not set up at that time, it can be entered later and the calendar event will be created. Therefore, I know that `if (e.changeType == "OTHER")` will need to be changed to `if (e.changeType == "OTHER" || "EDIT")` and that I can no longer use `sheet.getLastRow()`.

My question is what should I replace `sheet.getLastRow()` with and most importantly, how will I call/reference the row that was impacted by:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("Y:Y");
    if (e.changeType == "OTHER" || "EDIT")
```

Essentially, what do I need to set the current `var lastRow` equal to so that it will call the row where the change was made instead of the last row? (I will of course change the name of the variable from lastRow to something more applicable when I do so)

Original Code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

// Calendar to output requests
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('youremail@gmail.com');

// Creates an object from the last form submission
function getSubmission() {
  this.timestamp = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 9).getValue();
  this.accountNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 10).getValue();
  this.contactLastName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 11).getValue();
  this.contactFirstName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 12).getValue();
  this.contactPhoneNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 15).getValue();
  this.contactEmail = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 16).getValue();
  this.userLastName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 37).getValue();
  this.userFirstName = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 38).getValue();
  this.userPhoneNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 39).getValue();
  this.userEmail = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 40).getValue();
  this.streetAddress = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 17).getValue();
  this.city = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 18).getValue();
  this.state = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 19).getValue();
  this.zipCode = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 20).getValue();
  this.type = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 21).getValue();
  this.equipment = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 22).getValue();
  this.typeOfLead = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 13).getValue();
  this.sourceOfLead = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 14).getValue();
  this.notes = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 23).getValue();
  this.date = new Date(sheet.getRange(lastRow, 24).getValue());
  this.appointmentStart = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 25).getValue();
  this.appointmentEnd = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 26).getValue();
  this.direction = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 27).getValue();
  this.callOnWay = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 28).getValue();
  return this;
}

//  Creates a calendar event using the submitted data
function updateCalendar(request) {
  request.date.setHours(request.appointmentStart.getHours());
  request.date.setMinutes(request.appointmentStart.getMinutes());
  var endTime = new Date(request.date);
  endTime.setHours(request.appointmentEnd.getHours());
  endTime.setMinutes(request.appointmentEnd.getMinutes())
  var event = calendar.createEvent(
    request.state + " " + request.direction + " EST " + request.contactLastName + ", " + request.contactFirstName + " " + request.callOnWay,
    request.date,
    endTime
  )
  .setLocation(request.streetAddress + " " + request.city + ", " + request.state + " " + request.zipCode
  )
  .setDescription("Account # " + request.accountNumber + "\n" + "\n" + request.contactFirstName + " " + request.contactLastName + "\n" + request.contactPhoneNumber + "\n" + request.contactEmail + "\n" + "\n" + "Notes: " + request.type + " - " + request.equipment + ". " + request.notes + ".\n" + "Lead: " + request.typeOfLead + " - " + request.sourceOfLead + "." + "\n" + "\n" + "Jim: Scanned:____    " + "Inv. Adj:____    " + "QB:____    " + "Est. SL:____" + "\n" + "\n" + "Tracy: QB:____" + "    Scan:____" + "    Letter:____" + "    Lead Sheet:____" + "    Ref. Check #:____"
  )
}

// --------------Main--------------
function main() {
  var request = getSubmission();
  updateCalendar(request);
}

function runMain(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("Y:Y");
    if (e.changeType == "OTHER") {
    main();
    }
}
```

I am still quite new to writing in App Script, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Updated code with suggestions from @YuriKhristich:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

// Calendar to output requests to
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('youremail@gmail.com');

// Creates an object from the last submission
function getSubmission(row) {

  var data = sheet.getRange(row,9,1,40).getValues();

  this.timestamp          = row[ 9];
  this.accountNumber      = row[10];
  this.contactLastName    = row[11];
  this.contactFirstName   = row[12];
  this.contactPhoneNumber = row[15];
  this.contactEmail       = row[16];
  this.userLastName       = row[37];
  this.userFirstName      = row[38];
  this.userPhoneNumber    = row[39];
  this.userEmail          = row[40];
  this.streetAddress      = row[17];
  this.city               = row[18];
  this.state              = row[19];
  this.zipCode            = row[20];
  this.type               = row[21];
  this.equipment          = row[22];
  this.typeOfLead         = row[13];
  this.sourceOfLead       = row[14];
  this.notes              = row[23];
  this.date      = new Date(row[24]);
  this.appointmentStart   = row[25];
  this.appointmentEnd     = row[26];
  this.direction          = row[27];
  this.callOnWay          = row[28];
  return this;
}

//  Creates a calendar event using the submitted data
function updateCalendar(request) {
  request.date.setHours(request.appointmentStart.getHours());
  request.date.setMinutes(request.appointmentStart.getMinutes());
  var endTime = new Date(request.date);
  endTime.setHours(request.appointmentEnd.getHours());
  endTime.setMinutes(request.appointmentEnd.getMinutes())
  var event = calendar.createEvent(
    request.state + " " + request.direction + " EST " + request.contactLastName + ", " + request.contactFirstName + " " + request.callOnWay,
    request.date,
    endTime
  )
  .setLocation(request.streetAddress + " " + request.city + ", " + request.state + " " + request.zipCode
  )
  .setDescription("Account # " + request.accountNumber + "\n" + "\n" + request.contactFirstName + " " + request.contactLastName + "\n" + request.contactPhoneNumber + "\n" + request.contactEmail + "\n" + "\n" + "Notes: " + request.type + " - " + request.equipment + ". " + request.notes + ".\n" + "Lead: " + request.typeOfLead + " - " + request.sourceOfLead + "." + "\n" + "\n" + "Jim: Scanned:____    " + "Inv. Adj:____    " + "QB:____    " + "Est. SL:____" + "\n" + "\n" + "Tracy: QB:____" + "    Scan:____" + "    Letter:____" + "    Lead Sheet:____" + "    Ref. Check #:____"
  )
}

// --------------Main--------------
function main() {
  var request = getSubmission(lastRow);
  updateCalendar(request);
}

function runMain(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("Y:Y");
    if (e.changeType == "OTHER") {
    main();
    }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 25) return;
  var request = getSubmission(e.range.rowStart);
  updateCalendar(request);
}
```

Receiving the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined" when adding a new lead or editing appointment date.

runMain is being triggered via the installable trigger On Change.
Will an On Edit trigger need to be implemented to run the onEdit function or is that repetitive?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another installable trigger `onEdit` (either manually or in Apps Script) to check which row was edited and then call `getSubmission` with that row number as parameter.

```
function getRow(e) {
  var currentRow = e.range.getRow();
  var request = getSubmission(currentRow);
  updateCalendar(request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I am a novice, so having a bit of a tough time understanding exactly how to implement it. I think I understand how the code you listed will run, however, I am still unsure what to replace `var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();` with. As, just adding the code will run the function on any edit to the sheet, but will still pull info from the last row in the sheet rather than the edited one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the functions `getSubmission()` this way:

```
function getSubmission(row) { // <--  add 'row' argument here

  var data = sheet.getRange(row,9,1,40).getValues(); // make one call to server instead of 24

  this.timestamp          = row[ 9];
  this.accountNumber      = row[10];
  this.contactLastName    = row[11];
  this.contactFirstName   = row[12];
  this.contactPhoneNumber = row[15];
  this.contactEmail       = row[16];
  this.userLastName       = row[37];
  this.userFirstName      = row[38];
  this.userPhoneNumber    = row[39];
  this.userEmail          = row[40];
  this.streetAddress      = row[17];
  this.city               = row[18];
  this.state              = row[19];
  this.zipCode            = row[20];
  this.type               = row[21];
  this.equipment          = row[22];
  this.typeOfLead         = row[13];
  this.sourceOfLead       = row[14];
  this.notes              = row[23];
  this.date      = new Date(row[24]);
  this.appointmentStart   = row[25];
  this.appointmentEnd     = row[26];
  this.direction          = row[27];
  this.callOnWay          = row[28];
  return this;
}
```

Change the `main()` function this way:

```
function main() {
  var request = getSubmission(lastRow); // <-- add 'lastRow' argument here
  updateCalendar(request);
}
```

And add the `onEdit()` function:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 25) return; // if column Y
  // probably it makes sense to check the name of the sheet as well
  var request = getSubmission(e.range.rowStart);
  updateCalendar(request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @YuriKhristich I see how that allows there to only be one call to the database, and will put that into practice. I am struggling to understand what "row" should be set equal to? How am I telling it what row to call?

Comment: `e.range.rowStart` is a current row. I assumed you want to process the row you're editing. Don't you?

Comment: That is correct. I'll add the code that is running now in an to my original question. When I run the code, by submitting a new lead or editing by adding an appointment date & time, I receive the following failure message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined"

Comment: Well, basically the trigger `onEdit()` doesn't have access to any sources where is need authorization. So you can't made such requests in this full-automatic way. You can call the function from Script editor either via Custom menu. Another way, to make the trigger `onEdit()` installable. But I'm not a big expert in installable triggers. I'm not even sure if could be done at all with `onEdit()` trigger. It would be better if @CarlosM show us how it should be done. Perhaps I could to modify the script to make it works via the Custom menu.